# jQuery Image slider for ASP.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I want an image slider similar to what is shown in the link below.

http://blog.dreamcss.com/wp-content/uploads/example/

I have customized the script to my needs but I'm not able to find a way to change the image transition effect, rather than moving image from right to left I want image to dissolve & show other image that would make this script really code. I am open to new jQuery based Image Effect Slider/Gallery With similar look. This is the client's request so the design will remain same.

I would appreciate if i can change the image effect or if some one can provide me link for similar image slider.
I have to use this with ASP.Net and possible modify this script to integrated with database using c#

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these [Javascript Image and Photo Galleries](http://www.queness.com/post/633/30-javascript-image-and-photo-galleriesmootool-prototype-jquery-and-tutorials). I would recommend using the existing APIs provided by these script libraries using JSON to pass data to the client from the server as opposed to modifying the script -- keeps it simple.

Alternatively, you could look at some of the stuff on CodePlex: [Image Gallery](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=image%20gallery&sortBy=Relevance&tagName=,ASP.NET,&licenses=%7C&refinedSearch=true) if you wanted a server control to use with your solution.

Comment: These scripts are power but i want a similar functionality & design as shown in the example i only want to change image transition effect to fade in / fade out king on thing rest is fine,

Comment: Even thought it didn't match my requirement  but it has some good option so i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

I use Flex slider http://flex.madebymufffin.com/ , it is very customisable and lightweight and should do what you want

Comment: Can i customize it exactly what i have show in example, As i want to replace Paging circles with Numbers Paging

Comment: you definatly can, i'm just looking into how it can be done, will reply when i found it

Comment: script which you have show is cool but i am not able to find a way to customize so that it looks as i have show in the example. I appreciate your time.